# How can I run the original Diablo 1 in windowed mode?

Tags: diablo

I have Windows XP in a VM within OS X Lion, but I'd like to run *Diablo* in its own window for when I put Parallels in Coherence mode. I can't resize the window once it resets the resolution to 640x480 and goes full-screen. Is it possible to run it in a window within Windows without another VM? Adding the usual windowed mode flags (`-w`, `-win`, `-window`, `-windowed`) to the shortcut's target field doesn't work (though `-w` works with *D2*). (Is there another established method for windowing old, stubborn programs like *D1*?)

Comment: You can try running it in a virtual machine like Virtual Box.

Comment: Diablo doesn't have any native support for windowed mode. The only way I know is a virtual machine.

Comment: A Virtual machine works perfectly, if your pc isn't like 10 years old. Maybe someone should turn this into an answer.

Comment: Have you tried Alt+Enter?

Comment: @NickT Yep—no dice

Answer (score 6):

A virtual machine running on Virtual Box will probably do the trick. One of the main downsides of trying to run games on VM's is the slowdown from virtualizing modern graphics, which is totally not a problem here! Further, you should be able to avoid any windows compatibility problems by just installing Windows 98 in the VM.

Comment: 1 that would have been my suggestion as well...

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?805105-General-Introduction-Guide&p=7942869&viewfull=1#post7942869) offers some insightful information on installing D1 on Virtual Box.

- Get [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
- Get the [latest IPX/SPX Wrapper](http://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/) (to be extracted to the main game folder).
- An install CD/DVD/image of w/e your OS of choice.

> General > Advanced > Untick "Show Toolbar in Fullscreen;"
>
> Audio > Host Driver > Alsa Network > Bridged Adapter;
>
> [Select Windows as the installation media](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_VirtualBox_Virtual_Machines), then install;
>
> Install [guest additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadditions), then enable their offered graphics capabilities;
>
> Every time one restarts the virtual machine, consideration should be given to:
>
> Cut down host resolution (integer-value native division; aspect-ratio maintenance)
> through its system settings (useful for cases in which the resolution is of 640*480);
>
> Switch to fullscreen mode through holding down the host key*, then pressing the f one;
>
> Disable mouse integration through holding down the host key*, then pressing the i one;
>
> *By default, this is the right Control key on your keyboard; on a Mac host, the default host key is the left Command key

For more information on Virtual Box, consult the manual [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html).

[WineBottler](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1277412) works as well. The process is about the same as installing D2.